# Using an ajax form submit on codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

im trying to create a form in codeigniter with the help of jquery ajax but i seem to be having problems in making it work

what im trying to do is...

1. to create a form that will that will check if the user has filled up all the necessary fields before inserting the data into the database
2. if there is a field that does not contain any answer, a div will appear that says which fields needs to be answered
3. if all fields are filled up the form will submit, update the database and a div will appear saying that the form has successfully been submitted

here is my code

**controller**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Site extends CI_controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            // Your own constructor code
            $this->load->model("site_model");

            //$cms_db = $this->load->database('cms', TRUE); /* database conection for write operation */
            $site_db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);  
        } 
        public function index()
        {
        //$this->load->helper('form');

        $data = $this->_initialize_data();
        $data['about'] = $this->site_model->get_about();
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view('site/index');
        }

        public function learner()
        {
            $this->site_model->submit_learner();
            redirect(base_url() . "site/index");
        }

        public function _initialize_data()
        {
            $data['cp'] = $this->site_model->get_cp();
            $data['op'] = $this->site_model->get_op();
            $data['learnedu'] = $this->site_model->get_learnedu();
            $data['learnals'] = $this->site_model->get_learnals();
            $data['learnbrgy'] = $this->site_model->get_learnbrgy();
            $data['learnben'] = $this->site_model->get_learnben();
            return $data;
        }
}
```

**model**

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    //  CI 2.0 Compatibility
    if(!class_exists('CI_Model')) { class CI_Model extends Model {} }

    class Site_model extends CI_Model
    {

                function submit_learner()
        {
            //$this->load->helper('date');
            $cms_db = $this->load->database('cms', TRUE); 

                    $fname = $this->input->post("fname");
                    $mname = $this->input->post("mname");
                    $lname = $this->input->post("lname");
                    $ename = $this->input->post("ename");
                    $bday = $this->input->post("bday");
                    $opt = $this->input->post("opt");
                    $educ = $this->input->post("educ");
                    $als = $this->input->post("als");
                    $brgy = $this->input->post("brgy");
                    $guardian = $this->input->post("guardian");
                    $relation = $this->input->post("relation");
                    $benefit = $this->input->post("benefit");

                    $newdata = array('first_name'=>$fname,
                                        'middle_name'=>$mname,
                                        'last_name'=>$lname,
                                        'extension_name'=>$ename,
                                        'bday'=>$bday,
                                        'gender'=>$opt,
                                        'education'=>$educ,
                                        'als'=>$als,
                                        'brgy'=>$brgy,
                                        'guardian'=>$guardian,
                                        'relationship'=>$relation,
                                        'added_by'=>'OTH',
                                        'added_id'=>''
                                        );

                    $cms_db->insert('records', $newdata); 
                    $id = $cms_db->insert_id();

                    foreach($benefit as $b)
                    {
                        $ben = array('record_id'=>$id,'beneficiary_id'=>$b);
                        $cms_db->insert('is_beneficiary', $ben); 
                    }


                    $date = date('Y-m-d g:ia');

                    $date_logged = array('action'=>'Added','action_date'=>$date,'activity'=>$fname . " " . $mname . " " . $lname . ' was added through the Abot Alam Website');
                    $cms_db->insert('date_logged', $date_logged); 


        }
}
```

**view**

```
       <?php
        $attributes = array('class' => 'form-vertical','id'=>'form_learner','name'=>'form_learner');

        echo form_open(base_url() . 'site/learner', $attributes);
       ?>                   

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" >First Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="input input-xlarge" name="fname" id="fname"  placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>

/*-------- Theres a bunch of other fields here that asks things like last name, middle name but i decided to omit it to make the post shorter ----------------*/ 

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" placeholder="" name="submit_learner" id="submit_learner"> 
</form>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
         $("#submit_learner").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            fname = $("#fname").val();
            mname = $("#mname").val();
            lname = $("#lname").val();
            ename = $("#ename").val();
            bday = $("#bday").val();
            educ = $("#educ").val();
            als = $("#als").val();
            brgy = $("#brgy").val();
            guardian = $("#guardian").val();
            relation = $("#relation").val();

            if(fname==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input First Name</h4>");
                    $("#fname").focus();

                }

            else if(mname==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Middle Name</h4>");
                    $("#mname").focus();

                }

            else if(lname==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Last Name</h4>");
                    $("#lname").focus();

                }

            else if(ename==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Extention Name</h4>");
                    $("#ename").focus();

                }

            else if(bday==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Birthdate</h4>");
                    $("#bday").focus();

                }

            else if(educ==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Highest Formal Education</h4>");
                    $("#educ").focus();

                }

            else if(als==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input ALS Programs Involved</h4>");
                    $("#als").focus();

                }

            else if(brgy==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Barangay</h4>");
                    $("#brgy").focus();

                }

            else if(guardian==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Guradian</h4>");
                    $("#guradian").focus();

                }

            else if(relation==''){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Input Relationship to Guardian</h4>");
                    $("#relation").focus();

                }

            else{
                var datastr = 'fname='+fname + '&mname='+mname + '&lname='+lname + '&ename='+ename + '&bday='+bday + '&educ='+educ + '&als='+als + '&brgy='+brgy + '&guardian='+guardian + '&relation='+relation; 
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/learner",
                    type:'POST',
                    data:datastr,
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(result){
                    $("#learner_status").show();
                    $("#learner_status").attr('class', 'span 12 alert alert-success');
                    $("#learner_status").html("<h4>Form Successfully Submitted</h4>");
                    }

                });

                }

         });
```

i have a feeling that the error is somewhere around in my javascript

specially this line

```
$.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/learner",
```

correct me if im wrong but from what i know you can't use php tags inside script tags

but thats how people do it in other examples ive seen in the internet

am i missing something?

thanks

edit: btw i forgot to mention that the problem with my code is that it doesnt insert into the database.

Comment: If the php interpreter is not run against `scripts.js` (and it likely isn't), that php code won't be executed like you need.  It's better to have the JavaScript get that value from the DOM, perhaps in the `<base>` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, right before you load `script.js`, you could put this:

```
<script>var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'site/learner';</script>
```

The js-variable `base_url`should then be accessible to `script.js`, so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url, //etc
```

Comment: odd...i tried this but it still wont work. the problem maybe something different. is there anything else i may have missed?

Comment: There were a couple of single quotes missing in my original answer. Maybe try again with the updated code above?

Comment: just double checking. do i place <script>var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'site/learner';</script> inside my script.js? just tried it but still wont work

Comment: No, you place it in the `<head>`section of your view's `html`, then right under that you load the external `script.js`javascript file.

Comment: placed it in the head but the data still doesnt insert in the database

Comment: Are you using `url: base_url`in your script.js? Also, your dataType is `json` but you don't seem to be passing data in json format?